# How to Use Action Cable With an API-only Application Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, websocket, real-time, actioncable

I'm new to rails, I'm asked to implement a chat API application using rails, I have seen ActionCable but have seen that we must implement some frontend to connect the WebSocket, Is there any other way to make a real-time app just using requests from Postman, I'm not fully aware how this can be done, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also trying to figure out a solution. However this is what I have discovered so far.

1. I use Firecamp https://firecamp.io/ which has a WebSocket client to connect to my action cable server which has an endpoint at `ws://localhost:4000/cable>`
2. I use devise with devise-jwt for user authentication. See my action cable connection class below

```rb
    module ApplicationCable
      class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
      include Warden

      identified_by :current_user

      def connect
        self.current_user = find_verified_user!
      end

      def disconnect
        Rails.logger.info("Disconnected: #{self}")
      end

      protected
      
      def find_verified_user!
        token = request.headers["Authorization"].split(" ").second
        decoder = JWTAuth::UserDecoder.new
        decoder.call(token, :user, nil)
      rescue StandardError => e
        logger.debug(e)
        reject_unauthorized_connection
      end
    end
  end
```

So far this is what I have gathered. I'm able to create a connection from an authenticated user.

Now working on subscribing the verified user to a Channel. I will update this when I figure it out